# How to add quotes in visual basic?

Tags: command-line, visual-studio-2010, .net-framework

I'd like to ask how is it possible to add quotes in VB.
I'm trying to run command which contains quotes..
example:

> ```
>     Shell("cmd.exe")
>     SendKeys.Send("cd "c:\users\abc def" ")  <<<<--- this line
>     SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
> ```

there is an syntax error. 
the problem is that I need to add quotes to some commands as there is a space in folderpath.

As a beginner in VB I'm not really sure how to describe the poblem correctly so I hope you can see the it in my example :/

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another `"` (quote sign) before every quot sign you want to escape. No spaces.
Character escaping definition (thanks Wikipedia):

> In computing and telecommunication, an escape character is a character which invokes an alternative interpretation on subsequent characters in a character sequence. An escape character is a particular case of metacharacters. Generally, the judgement of whether something is an escape character or not depends on context.

And this question is off-topic here, anything regarding Programming should be asked in this site's brother, stackoverflow.